# How do I convert an input of -1 V ... +1 V to an output of 0 V ... +3.5 V using an MCP6022?

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, level-shifting

In the simulator I get the expected result:

- input: 1 V
- output: 2.10 V

[image]

But when I use hardware I don't get the correct output voltage.

Can anyone give me answer with best example?

Comment: Previously closed question on same subject: [I have +-1 V analog input I want to shift this signal to 0-3.5 V. What is the best way to do this?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/655078/i-have-1-v-analog-input-i-want-to-shift-this-signal-to-0-3-5-v-what-is-the-be). *I don't get the correct output voltage* <-- you had this kind of ambiguity in your previous question and despite me asking you to clarify it, you didn't. Saying you didn't get the correct output voltage is worthless compared to saying "I expected x volts but got y volts".

Comment: 1. Kindly tell us what output voltage you get on hardware. 2. What voltage do you connect on pin 8? Is it 5V? 3. What voltage do you see on pin 2 & pin 3 on hardware? Is it 1.66V? If you can provide answers to these 3 questions, we may be able to understand the issue.

Comment: If the simulation gives the right result and the physical circuit you built does not then you've most likely got an error in your build. Check it yet again. Get someone else to build one without looking at yours or to check yours against the schematic. If the circuit you built accurately matches the diagram, check you are actually simulating the same circuit.

Comment: Your title implies you want 3.5 volts out when the input is +1 volts but your opening bullet points says something different i.e. 2.1 volts out with +1 volts as an input.

Comment: Techno - Hi, You should not have reposted effectively the same question as your [last one](/q/655078). The etiquette on Stack Exchange for [closed questions](/help/closed-questions) is that you should have *edited that one* to have it considered for reopening. (There is [this related article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582) linked from the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931).) However, since *this* question now has an answer, your previous question has been deleted. Please don't repost to repeat/update a closed question again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your design is good, and should indeed produce +2.1V when the input is +1V. Here are some possible reasons why it doesn't in real life:

1. You have not built the circuit correctly, or you have included something that isn't in the schematic. I imagine you are rolling your eyes right now, adamant that you've built it perfectly. However, your design seems OK, and should work. This, in my opinion, is very likely to be the problem.
2. If you've plugged in a heavy output load or other element not in that schematic, it could skew your results. Can you say with certainty that there is absolutely nothing in your physical circuit that doesn't appear in this schematic?
3. If you are using a solderless breadboard, check continuity everywhere. Some of them have breaks where you don't expect them. Actually, check continuity regardless of the setup you use.
4. The op-amp is damaged. Perhaps you connected the power supply pins the wrong way around, once, and you don't realise it. It happens. Build the simplest voltage follower, to test if it still works.
5. You are not using an MCP6022. Perhaps a TL081 or something that will not behave well with inputs below +1.5V. Check the input voltage range for the op-amp you are using. Same goes for the output, don't expect rail-to-rail output range if you are not really using a rail-to-rail device.
6. You are using an MCP6022, but you've mistaken the pinout for another device from the datasheet. This is a dual op-amp package; don't get it mixed up with the MCP6021 or MCP6023, for example, which contain only one.
7. Resistor value is wrong. Double check all resistors, I misread them from time to time. And if you bought them from China, you can expect some to be badly labelled, or just plain broken.
8. You think your input is +1V, but it is not. You think the power supply is +5V, but it is not. Double check those voltages. I would like to know how you are generating your input signal, and how you know it's what you think it is.
9. You are measuring wrong, or you are expecting measurements that exactly match calculations. There's enough uncertainty in all those components, and your voltmeter, for the output to be 10% different from calculations. Unlikely to be that bad, but just saying.

Comment: I once knew an R&D engineer who measures every resistor before he soldered it into his breadboards - because he was colour blind! **BUT** he never got a value wrong due to a mis-marked component.